# Need information on SQL Injection in ASP.Net MVC 4

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, sql-injection

[image]

I have a report generated by IBM appscanner tool. It scanned my mvc application and on some urls it gave me high alerts.
 I'm trying to figure out how to perform parameter manipulation on my page like above information provided in the report to find the issue.
Example of the link on which the above report is based : `localhost:46887/Myproject/country/edit/1`

Comment: Doing SQL string concatenation are we? :)  Make sure to parameterized your query to avoid this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rule of a thumb: 
 Aways cast the values (provided through Request) to concrete type which are you using in the application logic. 
 If you are using ORM/ODM to access the data storage you recieve built in SQL injection protection :).
 This tool may be examins only the the query string and just assumes that injection is possible.

Comment: Yes i figured out the same. The query string value was being manipulated and i'm using LINQ and EF so It automatically is protected agains SQL injection.